# python: Creating Multiple Variables for Sensor

Tags: python

I have a Variable P01 (How many Sensor are in this System) (0-?).
I want to create a automatic Variable for every Sensor and assign a Value to it (mA from a RS-485 Modbus part)

```
Like: P01 is 2 
Then: Messwert_mA_1 is 16mA #(Messwert_mA_1 = write_ModbusRTU(ADDR_UART0, [3, 4, 0, 14, 0, 1]))
      Messwert_mA_2 is 8mA
```

After this i want to check P01 amount of Messwerte_mA_

Comment: Why not use a ```list```?

Comment: common problem - DON'T use separated variables but keep on list or in dictionary. `Messwert_mA[1] = "16mA"`

Comment: P01 = 5 #How much Sensor
P01 += 1 # For my Range

Messanfrage_RS_485_1 = 16
Messanfrage_RS_485_2 = 8
Messanfrage_RS_485_3 = 13
Messanfrage_RS_485_4 = 4
Messanfrage_RS_485_5 = 18
Messanfrage_RS_485_6 = 30


Messwert_mA = ["Platzhalter 1", Messanfrage_RS_485_1, Messanfrage_RS_485_2, Messanfrage_RS_485_3, Messanfrage_RS_485_4, Messanfrage_RS_485_5, Messanfrage_RS_485_6]
ppm = ["Platzhalter 1", None, None, None, None, None, None] 

for sens in range(1,P01):
    ppm[sens] = (Messwert_mA[sens] - 4) * 18.75
    print("Sensor" , sens ,": mA =" , Messwert_mA[sens], "PPM =" , ppm[sens])